# How to fix "M" value must be True or False

Tags: django, choicefield

[This is my model.py where my gender is a booleanfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGL78.png)

[This is my forms.py where i put my gender as a choicefield and the widget is radioselect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSWbq.png)

[Maybe my wrong is in the views.py but i don't know how to fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekrph.png)

[This is the error that i need to fix Please help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUngE.png)

Comment: DON'T use images to show your codes. DON'T. Nobody is going to walk through the image code.

Comment: @StickyFungus, do you own a git repository buddy?

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {'first_name': form.cleaned_data.get('first_name'), ....}
data['gender'] = True if form.cleaned_data.get('gender') == 'M' else False
mo = Monitor.objects.create(**data)
```